# Remove/Splice an Element of an Array after some seconds in Angular/Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I got this Code, which adds Callers to an Array, whenever the Server registers new Callers.

```
caller = new CallerData;
callers = new Array<CallerData>();

ngOnInit() {
            this.callService.exposeCallerObservable().subscribe(
                (x: CallerData) => {
                    this.caller = x;
                    this.callers.push(x);
           },
                (error: any) => {
                    console.warn("Could not subscribe to the Caller Observable!", error);
                }
            )
        }
```

Now I want to keep each Caller for only 5-10seconds in the array, and after this  time it should be removed again. Can you help me with that?

Comment: After `this.callers.push(x);` you can write something like `setTimeout(()=>{this.callers = [];},5000)`

Comment: perfect! thanks that is what I was looking for :)

Comment: I'll provide it as an answer then :-)

Comment: This clears the whole array after 5 seconds right? How would I have to modify this, so it tracks the 5 seconds for each new caller which gets pushed into the array and deletes them "one by one"?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the js `setTimeout` function

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.callService.exposeCallerObservable().subscribe(
        (x: CallerData) => {
            this.caller = x;
            this.callers.push(x);
            setTimeout(()=>{
                if(this.callers && this.callers.length > 0){
                    this.callers.shift();
                }
            },5000);
         }, 
         (error: any) => {
             console.warn("Could not subscribe to the Caller Observable!", error);
         });
}
```

Comment: This will remove all callers at once. I am not sure that's what OP wants. I mean what if a caller is emitted every second? Then the fifth one will be removed immediately

Comment: @TamasHegedus since OP commented "_perfect! thanks that is what I was looking for :)_" I assumed that is what OP was looking for :-) but of course splice could've been used to remove specific elements.

Comment: tamas is actually right :D i commented the question^^

Comment: @echonax trust noone. :D

Comment: @TamasHegedus, reveN I edited my answer with the pop() method. This will remove the last element from the array every 5 seconds. Not sure if I'm stepping into another async trap here:-) do we need to keep the reference id of the timeout and reset it everytime this method is called?

Comment: Yup, I dont want any caller to stay longer than 5seconds in the array. As there is a high amount of incoming callers this will lead to the first caller always be displayed, which is not intended

Comment: No, sorry its hard to clarify as english is not my first language.. I don't want any caller to be in the array for longer than 5 seconds. With your solution the first caller is in the array all the time, because to many new callers get pushed into the array. (i hope that makes sense :D)

Comment: Oh ok I switched pop() with shift(), how about now?

Comment: This removes the first element which is better but still "cheating" somehow :D Example: caller 1 gets pushed into the array. 3 seconds later caller 2 gets pushed in. this means that for 2 seconds both are in and after that caller 2 stays in another 5 seconds as the timer "resets" when he moves to the first position of the array. So caller to is in the array for 7 seconds instead of 5. U know what i mean? If there isnt a solution that tracks exactly 5 seconds for each caller the shift is probably the best it gets :D thanks

Comment: No no I get what you mean, I will try to fix it before TamasHegedus gives the perfect answer ;D I'm at work right now so it's taking a while to write the code.